# How to use a custom Kafka Streams ProductionExceptionHandler?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Im developing a kafka-streams application but am having trouble overriding the default ProductionExceptionHandler. 
 
I have created a class implementing the ProductionExceptionHandler

```
public class RtaCustomProcessingExceptionHandler implements ProductionExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RtaCustomProcessingExceptionHandler.class);
    private RtaHandlerClient handlerClient;

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map) {
        handlerClient = RtaHandlerClient.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public ProductionExceptionHandlerResponse handle(final ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record,
                                                     final Exception exception) {
        log.debug("PASSING");

        return ProductionExceptionHandlerResponse.CONTINUE;
    }
}
```

and added that to my properties

```
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_PRODUCTION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            RtaCustomProcessingExceptionHandler.class);
```

which I use to instanciate KafkaStreams

```
this.streams = new KafkaStreams(BasicTopology.createTopology(config), config.asProperties());
```

When the application is starting up I can see in the log that my handler is beeing picked up

```
[2018-10-10 07:58:40,471] INFO StreamsConfig values: 
    application.id = xdr-0
    application.server = 
    bootstrap.servers = [kafka-1:9092]
    buffered.records.per.partition = 1000
    cache.max.bytes.buffering = 10485760
    client.id = 
    commit.interval.ms = 1000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.deserialization.exception.handler = class org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndFailExceptionHandler
    default.key.serde = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$ByteArraySerde
    default.production.exception.handler = class com.ericsson.dcp.rtang.kafka.streams.xdr.error.handler.RtaCustomProcessingExceptionHandler
    default.timestamp.extractor = class org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.WallclockTimestampExtractor
    default.value.serde = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$ByteArraySerde
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
```

But then later in the log it seems to be overwriten for some odd reason that I cant understand

```
 [2018-10-10 07:58:40,958] INFO StreamsConfig values: 
    application.id = xdr-0
    application.server = 
    bootstrap.servers = [kafka-1:9092]
    buffered.records.per.partition = 1000
    cache.max.bytes.buffering = 10485760
    client.id = xdr-0-99215001-f1fd-43ae-8c3f-026cbd11d013-StreamThread-1-consumer
    commit.interval.ms = 30000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.deserialization.exception.handler = class org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndFailExceptionHandler
    default.key.serde = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$ByteArraySerde
    default.production.exception.handler = class org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.DefaultProductionExceptionHandler
    default.timestamp.extractor = class org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.FailOnInvalidTimestamp
    default.value.serde = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$ByteArraySerde
```

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?
BR
-Jiinxy

**EDIT**: Updated with actual handler implementation by request.

**EDIT2**: Ive set up my testing so I enque 10 items for processing wheres the 6th item contains a value that should cause an exception typically my own `public class RtaRecoverableProcessingException extends ApiException` but also `RecordTooLargeException` which both should be caught by a custom handler as far as I understand. Ive also added break-points to [RecordCollectorImpl.java](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/RecordCollectorImpl.java#L164-L202) at line 162(`producer.send(..` and 166 (`if(exception..` I can see that for the first five items the process passes correctly both line 162 and 166. However when the exception is thrown line 166 is not passed. From what I can tell It should be passing line 166 even if an exceptions is thrown since it seems to be handled at line 191(`else if (productionExceptionHandler.handle..`).

Comment: It's bug in Streams -- the first printed config is the correct one. You can ignore the second one. It's fixed in upcoming 2.1 release via https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/5389

Answer (score 2):

your kafka streams exception handler `RtaCustomProcessingExceptionHandler` is correct and should work. 
you could test it by putting breakpoint inside method `handle` of your `ProductionExceptionHandler`, and emulate exceptional case (e.g. throw any exception during processing message).

even from your first part of logs you see that `default.deserialization.exception.handler` is applied. second part of provided logs is for internal needs of kafka streams, and it takes default config values (if you compare other properties like `commit.interval.ms`, you also will see that all properties are default one).

Comment: Yes, I think so to. The application utilizes some custom exception to that are beeing thrown at different occations but Ive also tried throwing a native 'RecordTooLargeException' exception but my handler never gets called. Ive tried to debug it but as expected the handler is never called and I have a bit of trubble understanding the call-structure so Im not realy sure where I would expect the handler to be called.

Comment: please provide your `RtaCustomProcessingExceptionHandler` implementation, and also specify in which place you tried to throw exception? inside `map()`, `process()` or something else?

Comment: also which version of Kafka streams do you use?

Comment: Ive updated the original post with the current (very simple) implementation of the exception-handler. Exceptions are thrown as part of the map-step in a simple `stream.map(...).to(...);`-statement. The Kafka-streams version is 2.0.0.

Comment: Wooow.. something odd just happened. While running in debug-mode for the xxx-time all of a sudden the debugger stoped at my break-point in the handler!!! as intended. But when I re-run it now its back to skipping the handler!! Realy odd? My Implementation is realy simple so I cant for the life of me understand how this could happen. It actually happened before but I was so puzzled that I thought I must have been misstaken but now Im sure it happende. Do you have any idea how this could happen? Bug in Streams?

Comment: Sounds weird. Try to set a break point here to see what Kafka Streams is doing internally: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/RecordCollectorImpl.java#L164-L202

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Please find my latest update in the original post above. I have only had time to test this brieafly.

Comment: @Jiinxy I don't fully understand your update. What kind of exception to you try to simulate? Note, that the handler does not cover all exception? Also note, that the `Callback` is executed async. Also, there is a different is `send()` is throwing an exception directly (not covered) and if the broker return an error (this case will result in an exception in the `Callback`). What do you mean by "However when the exception is thrown line 166 is not passed" -- do you mean that the `Callback` does have `exception == null` ? If it's not a broker error, this would be expected.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Sorry for beeing abit unclear - Ive tried with a number of exceptions including `RecordTooLargeException` and my own `public class RtaRecoverableProcessingException extends ApiException` an none work. What I ment with line 166 not thrown was that the `Callback()` does not even seem to be entered when the exception is thrown.

Comment: How do you similar that an exception is thrown? It's unclear to me, how you could simulate throwing a custom `ApiException`? For `RecordTooLargeException` I thought that you put in a record that is actually too large on purpose to trigger the exception -- but I am not sure about this any longer. Do you connect to an actual broker in your test?

Comment: No, I just randomly used `RecordTooLargeException` to debug as I assumed that would be a valid exception to be caught by my handler (in case there would be somthing wrong w my exception). I will use a custom exception as soon as I get the handler working. The test-scenario is this - I process a stream of 10 items an if I come a cross an item with faulty value (in record 6) I throw a `new RecordTooLargeException();`. The idea is that this item will then be passed to the handler for processing and the stream-processing will continue.